# Objective-C linker error in 2 libraries

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, linker-errors

I work with 2 libraries in the same project. One require setting key "Other Linker Flags", one don't require.

For the first library, "Other Linker Flags" must be set to "-ObjC" and "-all_load" to run properly. But if so, the second library go to compiled error:

> ld: duplicate symbol _parseAdvertizeTag in /Users/Applehouse/working/joshibu/svn/B_SOURCE/ProGir/ProGir/CCIAd/libCCIMobile-Release.a(TagParser.o) and /Users/Applehouse/working/joshibu/svn/B_SOURCE/ProGir/ProGir/CCIAd/libCCIMobile-Debug.a(TagParser.o) for architecture i386
>       clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

The error occur only when I set the flags. If I don't use the first library, I set the setting "Other Linker Flags" as no values, there's no error, the second library run properly.

How do I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Look carefully at the error message. You are linking both the Debug (libCCIMobile-Debug.a) and Release (libCCIMobile-Release.a) version of the library at the same time.

Link only the debug version for your debug builds, and only the release version for your release builds.

Comment: hi Shaggy Frog: If I don't use the first library, I set the setting "Other Linker Flags" as no values, there's no error, the second library run properly. The error occur only when I set the flags.

Comment: @camdaochemgio You are trying to link two copies of the same library, which only differ from how they were themselves compiled (one with debug settings, one with release settings). Look at the compiler error: they both reference the same symbol (`_parseAdvertizeTag`) from the same compilation unit (`TagParser.o`). Whatever else is going on, this is definitely a problem. (And possibly your only problem.)

Answer (score 0):

You are included a two libraries at one target. That's is wrong.

Because in this two libraries a many same values. First is a _parseAdvertizeTag error.

You must use in 1 target only libCCIMobile-Release.a or libCCIMobile-Debug.a

Comment: @@Crea If I set the setting "Other Linker Flags" as no values, the second library run properly. The error occur only when I set the flags